# moment.js startOf issue

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to get the start and end of a day (which is a few days from today) using `moment.js`. This is the code I have:

```
var today = moment();
var day = today.add(-5, "days");
var startOfDay = day.startOf("day");
var endOfDay = day.endOf("day");

console.log("today " + today.format());
console.log("day " + day.format());
console.log("start " + startOfDay.format());
console.log("end " + endOfDay.format());
```

And these are the logs:

```
I2015-11-10T15:19:02.930Z]today 2015-11-10T15:19:02+00:00
I2015-11-10T15:19:02.931Z]day 2015-11-05T15:19:02+00:00
I2015-11-10T15:19:02.932Z]start 2015-11-05T23:59:59+00:00
I2015-11-10T15:19:02.933Z]end 2015-11-05T23:59:59+00:00
```

As you can see, the `start` and `end` dates are exactly the same. The `end` date is as expected, however, the `startOf` function appears to be doing exactly what the `endOf` function does.

Is there perhaps something I am missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Dates are mutable, and are altered by the method calls. Your two dates are both actually the same date object.  That is, `day.startOf("day")` returns the value of `day` both times you call it. You can make copies however:

```
var startOfDay = moment(day).startOf("day");
var endOfDay = moment(day).endOf("day");
```

That constructs two new instances.

Comment: I just tested it, your suggestion works perfectly. Thanks! Just to clarify - `startOf` and `endOf` functions mutate the `day` object? I assumed that they returned a new date object which I would then assign to a new variable. I guess I shouldn't assume.. :)

Comment: @artooras right, the functions that change date values (like those, and `.add()` etc) all change the underlying object *and* return that object so that you can chain to other functions. Personally I think it's a bad design choice but the underlying Date instances behave the same way.

Comment: _Note to Self_ `startOf` and `endOf` functions sit under the **Manipulate** section in `moment.js` documentation, which (somewhat) clearly implies they mutate the object. And my `startOfDay` and `endOfDay` variables simply point to the (already mutated) `day` object.